# Subgroup of free group on two elements free of rank $6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, free-groups

Let $F$ be the free group on two elements $x$, $y$. To make our lives easier, we denote $x^{-1}$ by $X$ and $y^{-1}$ by $Y$. Let $g_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 6$ be the following elements:$$g_1 = xyxY,$$$$g_2 = XYXyxYxyXyxYXYXyxYxyxyXYY,$$$$g_3 = XYXyx,$$$$g_4 = YxyXyxYXYXyyx,$$$$g_5 = YxyXYxyxyX,$$$$g_6 = xxYXXy.$$Let $G$ be the subgroup of $F$ generated by the $g_i$.

**Question.** How do I see that $G$ is free of rank $6$?

Comment: Are you aware of Nielson reduction? You could also use Stalling folding? Did you just write down 6 random words or do these come from somewhere?

Comment: When you wrote "...to make our lives easier..." you actually meant "...to make **my** life easier...", right? Anwyay, (1) you can check all the elements given are in reduced normal form, and (2) multiplying two of those elements doesn't result in  trivial reduction. Not that it will be terribly hlepful, but for what it's wroth $\;g_6\in F'\;$ as the final exponent sums in all its letters ($\;x,y\;$ and its inverses ) is zero.

Comment: I can see two immediate simplifcations. $g_3$ is a prefix of $g_2$, so you could remove that prefix. After doing that, $g_2$ and $g_4$ have a long common prefix, which you could use to further  shorten $g_2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in free goups, but I'll give it a go:
simplifying the generators like @Derek suggested:

$$g_1 = x\color{red}{yx}Y,$$
$$g_2 = XYx\color{red}{YxyxyXY}Y,$$
$$g_3 = XY\color{red}{X}yx,$$
$$g_4 = YxyX\color{red}{yxYXYXy}yx,$$
$$g_5 = YxyX\color{red}{Yxyxy}X,$$
$$g_6 = x\color{red}{xYX}Xy.$$
$$G_1 = y\color{red}{XY}X,$$
$$G_2 = y\color{red}{yxYXYXy}Xyx,$$
$$G_3 = XY\color{red}{x}yx,$$
$$G_4 = XY\color{red}{YxyxyXY}xYXy,$$
$$G_5 = x\color{red}{YXYXy}xYXy,$$
$$G_6 = Yx\color{red}{xyX}X$$
Now consider all possible concatenations $g_ig_j, G_ig_j, g_iG_j, G_iG_j$ (with $i\neq j$). You will see that the red part of the words never cancel (provided I didn't make a mistake). This implies that in any concatenation of arbitrary length of the $G$'s and $g$'s, the red part will never cancel. This means that there are no relations possible between them, and they indeed form a free group of rank $6$.

Comment: What is the generating set of the subgroup of rank 6 in terms of $g_i$? @Simon